# How to encode 2 dimentional PHP array to Javascript Array?

Tags: php, json, javascript

Here's my problem, i have a php array like this:

```
$output = array(array(1,1,1,1),array(2,2,2,2),array(3,3,3,3));
```

after the array was encoded to json i got this:

```
$output = {"1":[1,1,1,1],"2":[2,2,2,2],"3":[3,3,3,3]}
```

all i want is to pass the PHP array to Javascript so that the JS looks like this:

```
var output = [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3,]];
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

Which version of PHP are you using ?

With PHP 5.2.10, I get what you're asking for :

```
$output = array(array(1,1,1,1),array(2,2,2,2),array(3,3,3,3));
$json = json_encode($output);

echo $json . "\n";
```

Outputs :

```
$ php temp.php
[[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]]
```

*At least, this is without the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option -- that was added in PHP 5.3*

Maybe you can find something interesting in the user notes on the [`json_encode` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) ?

For instance, [simoncpu says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#94157) :

> A note of caution: If you are
>   wondering why json_encode() encodes
>   your PHP array as a JSON object
>   instead of a JSON array, you might
>   want to double check your array keys
>   because json_encode() assumes that you
>   array is an object if your keys are
>   not sequential.

And if you search for [json_encode+array+object](http://bugs.php.net/search.php?cmd=display&search_for=json_encode+array+object&x=0&y=0) on PHP's bugtracker, maybe you'll get some interesting result ?

*(For instance, something that says this was a bug, which has been corrected in recent versions of PHP ?)*

Comment: i think there was an error in json_encode in multi-dimentional array...any ideas?

Comment: Wow, Trez. Shame on you for treating a good answer so carelessly.

Comment: @adam, can u give me other solutions so that it will work in version 5.2.1

Comment: sorry guys, i was so confused on the above answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your original solution works for me:

```
adam@fsck:~:0$ php -r 'echo json_encode(array(array(1,1,1,1),array(2,2,2,2),array(3,3,3,3)));'
[[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]]
```