# PHP two dimensional array to Javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I had php multi dimensional array

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [WorkHrs] => 9826
            [Focus_Date] => 2010-02-10 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [WorkHrs] => 9680            
            [Focus_Date] => 2010-02-11
        )

)
```

and I want to convert it in Javascript to

```
 myArray = [['2010-02-10', 9826],['2010-02-11', 9680]];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encode 2 dimentional PHP array to Javascript Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249785/how-to-encode-2-dimentional-php-array-to-javascript-array)

Comment: @deceze, no, that's different.  Here, the inner arrays are associative.

Comment: @Matthew Sorry, you're right, but it's very related at least. :)

Comment: @mapet You should point out the specific problem you're struggling with. A question with this title pops up about twice a week, hence the one-word `json_encode` answers and my automatic duplicate-reflex. If you have already tried that, point out what didn't work or what's special about your case. Not everybody is going to read your code in such detail as to spot the intricate differences (we're all staring at code all day already), so pointing them out explicitly will get you better answers.

Comment: @deceze sorry next time i will.. tnx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$jsArray = array();
foreach($myArray as $array) {
   $jsArray[] = array($array['Focus_Date'], (int) $array['WorkHrs']); 
}

echo json_encode($jsArray);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
echo json_encode(array_map(array_values, $arr));
```

EDIT: To get it in the specified order:

```
function to_focus_work_array($arr)
{
  return array($arr['Focus_Date'], $arr['WorkHrs']);
}

echo json_encode(array_map('to_focus_work_array', $arr));
```

Comment: +1 for `array_values()`. Attempting to encode associative arrays results in JSON objects, therefore you need to remove the associative keys.

Comment: This won't give the values in the desired order though. :)

Answer (score 1):

[json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode)

Comment: hi david i try it before but the example of php.net is not two dimensional array :(

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much exactly what json_encode does. Input is a PHP-array (other datatypes accepted), output is what you describe.

Comment: No, if he uses `json_encode` directly, the output will be an array of JSON objects.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the json_encode()?
refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php